# JavaScript "Array" function with a numerical parameter

Tags: javascript

`Array(10)` is used here to generate an array of numbers.

```
Array.from(Array(10).keys());
```

What is this function?: `Array()`

Where can I find documentation on it?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Comment: It is same as `new Array()`. [Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Syntax)

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Syntax

> new Array(arrayLength)
>
> If the only argument passed to the Array constructor is an integer between 0 and 2<sup>32</sup>-1 (inclusive), this returns a new JavaScript array with its length property set to that number (Note: this implies an array of arrayLength empty slots, not slots with actual undefined values). If the argument is any other number, a RangeError exception is thrown.

So `Array.from(Array(n).keys())` is shorthand for "Create a new array of numbers 0 to `n - 1`".